# Creating product page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

First: I have very little knowledge in WordPress, but i'm doing fine with frontend, PHP and mySQL.

What I have, is a list of products, each product belongs to a `category` and has:

1. name
2. picture
3. description
4. list of specifications
5. list of links

I want to create posts or pages(?) for these products (no need to .

Where and how do I begin to create a "system" that will add this ability to my wordpress theme?
My theme is an empty one, the most basic theme.

I don't ask for the code of course, but i have no idea where to start?
What terms to google?
How to approach it?

thanks

Comment: You should use Woocommerce plugin. It will create page automatic to show products.

Comment: thanks @HelpingHands, but i am trying to learn how to do it myself.

Comment: Then I think you need HTML layout of products and then you can convert to it in wordpress and it will be done by creating custom template :)

Comment: I think so as well, and i have the HTML & css. trying to get the backend concept

Comment: define your custom post tyep (https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) and add some custom field in post edit page for your post type and save all data as post meta, you can retrieve those data using get_post_meta.